# Vertex AI: Requested Metadata Store default not found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

When I navigate to Vertex AI on GCP and try to create an experiment, I am faced with this error; Requested Metadata Store default not found and I am unable to proceed.

[image]

What is causing this and how do I resolve it?

Comment: If you go back to your dashboard and create a dataset in us-central1, can you then move forward?

Comment: It does! Thank you. Please add this as an answer if you wish to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your Dashboard in Vertex AI, and create a dataset first an example, and then you should be able to create an experiment